# In SQL - how can I count the number of times Bit(0), Bit(1), ... Bit(N) are high for a decimal number?

Tags: mysql, sql

I am dealing with a table of decimal values that represent binary numbers. My goal is to count the number of times Bit(0), Bit(1),... Bit(n) are high.

For example, if a table entry is 5 this converts to '101' which can be done using the BIN() function.

What I would like to do is increment a variable 'bit0Count' and 'bit2Count'

I have looked into the BIT_COUNT() function however this would only return 2 for the above example.

Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I can read this question as meaning any of three different things, or more I haven't thought of.  Please show some sample data and expected results for that sample data.

Comment: I have an idea what Bit(X) means, but I can't understand how it can be high.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT SUM(n & (1<<2) > 0) AS bit2Count FROM ...
```

The `&` operator is a [bitwise AND](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/bit-functions.html#operator_bitwise-and).

`1<<2` is a number with only 1 bit set, [left-shifted](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/bit-functions.html#operator_left-shift) by two places, so it is binary 100. Using bitwise AND against you column `n` is either binary 100 or binary 000.

Testing that with `> 0` returns either 1 or 0, since in MySQL, boolean results are literally the integers 1 for true and 0 for false (note this is not standard in other implementations of SQL).

Then you can SUM() these 1's and 0's to get a count of the occurrences where the bit was set.

Answer (score 1):

To tell if bit `N` is set, use `1 << N` to create a mask for that bit and then use bitwise AND to test it. So `(column & (1 << N)) != 0` will be `1` if bit N is set, `0` if it's not set.

To total these across rows, use the `SUM()` aggregation function.

If you need to do this frequently, you could define a stored function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION bit_set(UNSIGNED INT val, TINYINT which) DETERMINISTIC
    RETURN  (val & (1 << which)) != 0;
```